# listings is undefined angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a variable declared inside the component as follows,

```
public listings: ListingSeller[];
```

am getting the data from an api and pushing to the above array using foreach inside the OnInit,but it says listings is undefined.

```
 this.eventService.getListingsByEventId(this.eventId).subscribe(listresults => {
            this.bindListing(listresults);
        }, error => this.errorMessage = error);
    }
    bindListing(listres: any[]) {
        listres.forEach(function (data) {
            data.ticket.seating.forEach(function(seat:any) {
                this.listings.push(data);
            });
        })
    }
```

Comment: update the post with **ListingSeller** interface properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined the type but did not create an instance so you cant push to it yet as the reference is still undefined.

```
public listings: ListingSeller[] = [];
```

will fix the problem. (adding `= [];`) as this creates an empty array.

Also you need to use an [arrow function](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/arrow-functions.html) so that `this` points to the correct instance that the code is executing in and not the browser window.

```
this.eventService.getListingsByEventId(this.eventId).subscribe(listresults => {
            this.bindListing(listresults);
        }, error => this.errorMessage = error);
    }
    bindListing(listres: any[]) {
        listres.forEach((data) => { // use arrow function HERE
            data.ticket.seating.forEach((seat:any) => { // AND HERE
                this.listings.push(data);
            });
        })
    }
```

Comment: it did not work, cannot read property 'listings' of undefined

Comment: @user2280016 - see update, you need to use `arrow` functions OR get a reference to `this` to use inside of the `function`.